# Php Log In If-Else

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php include "konek.php"; 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $schoUsername = $_POST['schoUsername'];
    $schoPassword = $_POST['schoPassword'];
    $schoPosition = $_POST['schoPosition'];
            $password = sha1($schoPassword);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblscholar WHERE schoUsername = '$schoUsername' AND schoPassword = '$password' ";
    $conn = db_connect();
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row_num = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    if($row_num != 0)
    {  
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblscholar WHERE schoUsername = '$schoUsername' AND schoPassword = '$password'";
     $connect = db_connect();
     $res = $connect->query($sql);
     $row_num = mysqli_num_rows($res); 
     if($schoPosition == 'Spiritual_and_Community_Services_Committee_Head')
            header("Location:DashboardForSCSCH.php");
        else    
            header("Location:DashboardForUser.php"); }
    else 
     {  echo "invalid"; } }?>
```

Here is the konek.php

```
<?php
function db_connect() {

$result = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'simbayanan');

if (!$result) return false;
return $result; } ?>
```

I want it to be like, if your position is admin, you will be directly go to the dashboard of  admin, and when your position is librarian, you will directly go to the dashboard of librarian and vice versa. Everytime I login, the page is redirecting in dashboardforuser.php

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: And what is the problem? This code looks like work, isn't it? What is `konek.php` content?

Comment: no. it does not working.

Comment: then something missing  in DashboardForUser.php where is session settings happening

Comment: @LeRandomGirl, so give us more information. This code looks like work. We don't know about other files. What is `konek.php` content. Does it contain any html outputs? What about `dashboard*.php`?

Comment: how do i add my the "position" in my session?

Comment: should `$password` not be `$schoPassword` ?

Comment: i forgot to add
    $password = sha1($schoPassword);

Comment: why are you using the same query 2 times, you can get the results from first one if result count > 0

Comment: `how do i add my the "position" in my session?`: you can use `$_SESSION`. `$_SESSION['position'] = something;`

Comment: How? could youshow me how?

Comment: @MTahir could you show me how?

Comment: See the answer below by `Charlie Liu`

Answer (score 1):

Add exit to break the flow

```
 if($schoPosition == 'Spiritual_and_Community_Services_Committee_Head')
        header("Location:DashboardForSCSCH.php");
        exit();
    else    
        header("Location:DashboardForUser.php");
        exit(); 
               }
else 
 {  echo "invalid"; } }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php include "konek.php"; 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$con = db_connect();
$schoUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['schoUsername'],$con);
$schoPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['schoPassword'],$con);
$schoPosition = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['schoPosition'],$con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblscholar WHERE schoUsername = '$schoUsername' AND schoPassword    =     '$password' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row_num = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
if($row_num != 0)
{  
switch ($schoPosition) {
case 'Spiritual_and_Community_Services_Committee_Head':
    header("Location:DashboardForSCSCH.php");
    break;
case 1:
    header("Location:DashboardForAdmin.php");
    break;
case 2:
    header("Location:DashboardForLibrarian.php");
    break;
default: 
    header("Location:DashboardForUser.php");
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIMBAYANANIMARIA\indexForUser.php on line 11

Comment: just pass in your connection, I haven't tested the code myself so there may be errors. This will solve the SQL injection thing smistry talked about in your OP

Comment: i've edited my code. check the konek.php